# Почему один и тот же код работает по разному на Windows и Linux?

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Есть программа, изначально написана под виндой на Qt Creator компилятор MinGW. И есть программа, которая общается с модулем modbus slave. Программа под виндой вылетает, когда я вывожу график токов, а именно когда я график начинаю двигать, приближать/отдалять.

Скомпилировал я значит эту программу под линуксом, подключаю устройство (модуль Modbus Slave). Захожу в графики, и начинаю с ними играть. И вот уже 45 000 пакетов и программа не вылетает. Никаких помех, код работает как часы. А под виндой, если двигать графики, сразу "Прекращена работы программы "бла бла бла"".

Вот почему так? Под линуксом хорошо, а под виндой такие дела?

Comment: И ещё: я пробовал также компилятор MVC2015 - результат такой же

Comment: Возможно тот, кто писал под винду допустил где-то ошибку. Запустите под отладчиком программу и посмотрите где падает так будет понятнее. А лучше с этой проблемой на баг трекер Qt: https://bugreports.qt.io

Comment: Я писал эту программу. И писалось это изначально под винду. Только под этой же виндой программа вылетает, как только я начинаю играть с графиком. А под линуксом всё отлично. Я не фанат линукса и винды. Мне не важно под какой ОС работать. Но проблема есть. Как её решить - я не знаю. Я готов заплатить за помощь. Но никто не откликнулся.

Comment: Я говорил про разработчика библиотеки, с помощью которой вы графики рисуете, я предположил что она тоже в Qt входит :)

Comment: Нет нет. Библиотека графиков это QCustomPlot. Эта библиотека не входит в состав Qt Creator. Да и разве дело в библиотеке, если под линуксом всё хорошо?

Comment: Qt Creator -- это IDE (среда разработки), а фреймворк которым вы пользуетесь называется Qt, и эта библиотека связана с фреймворком Qt. У нее и классы на `Q` называются. Попробуйте для начала создать минимальный проект с проблемой (данные в нем могут быть синтетическими, прямо в коде забитыми) и попробовать. Запускайте в демаге с отладчиком, так хотя бы можно будет узнать место падения (или в коде добавьте через qDebug логирование в консоль чтобы отследить последную строку перед падением). Нужно отсечь варианты возможных проблем.

Comment: Ах да, вы еще не написали версию Qt

Comment: Qt Creator 4.2.1
Основан на Qt 5.8.0 (MSVC 2015, 32 бита)

Comment: Было бы хорошо, если бы Вы выделили 10 минут для меня и мы бы связались по Team Viewer и Вы бы увидели проблему. Так как не все проблемы можно отловить отладчиком. Я рад и оплатить Ваше время.

Comment: Я на работе и у меня нет времени и возможности. Вы написали версию Qt Creator, а какой Qt используете при сборке проекта? В Tools/Options/Build & Run в вкладке Kits есть наборы сборок проекта -- это сама Qt, компилятор и отладчик. И для сборки вы выбираете один из наборов. Так какая версия Qt у вас используется?

Comment: Кст, если кроме меня сюда никто не заглянет чтобы вам помочь, попробуйте спросить так же: http://www.prog.org.ru/index.php это русскоязычный форум Qt

Comment: Desktop Qt 5.8.0 MinGW 32bit

Comment: Да я и сам на работе. Мне скоро проект сдавать. А программа работает только под линуксом хорошо. Просто можно было встретится в скайпе к примеру. После работы или на выходных. Как Вы на это смотрите? Код сам по себе не сложный. Да и в долгу не останусь.

Comment: Я откажусь: не желания и вряд ли смогу вам помочь (это главное). Тут я пытаюсь вам помочь, вытащив из вас информацию о написанной вами программе и использованных в ней компонентах. И как я выше советовал напишите синтаксический мини пример с проблемой и выложите его, чтобы желающие помочь могли у себя проверить. Возможно выйдет так, что минимальный пример у вас будет работать хорошо и тогда проблема будет не связана с QCustomPlot, а с чем-то другим. А если и минимальный пример не будет работать, тогда с ним можно обратиться в багтрекер. Еще можно попробовать на более старой версии Qt проверить

Comment: Мини примера не будет, потому что у людей, которые хотят помочь попросту не смогут у себя проверить этот код. Потому что им надо такое же устройство как у меня. А устройство это даже не моё, а я предприятия

Comment: Устройство шлет поток данных, вы что-то с этими данными делаете и отображаете это на графике. Заводите такие данные (или подобные ими) и отображаете. Все-равно, без кода сложно сказать в чем проблема

Comment: QCustomPlot - это всего лишь два файла исходников, *.cpp и *.h.
В чём проблема запустить свою программу из-под отладчика - не понимаю.  У меня, например, и под Windows  и под Linux QCustomPlot работает и не вылетает.